# check for occurrence of | in a complex string

Tags: python, perl, grep, awk, regex

The basic requirement is that I need to find the occurrence of `|` in `BasicRule` of NAXSI web application firewall whitelist

```
BasicRule  wl:1015 "mz:$URL:/js/));Nt.optgroup=Nt.option,Nt.tbody=Nt.tfoot=Nt.colgroup=Nt.caption=Nt.thead,Nt.th=Nt.td,v.support.htmlSerialize||(Nt._default=[1,|URL";
```

is invalid rule because of the `||` in the `$URL` regular expression

```
BasicRule  wl:1015 "mz:$URL:/js/));Nt.optgroup=Nt.option,Nt.tbody=Nt.tfoot=Nt.colgroup=Nt.caption=Nt.thead,Nt.th=Nt.td,v.support.htmlSerialize(Nt._default=[1,|URL";
```

is valid

NAXSI whitelists are of syntax as described in https://github.com/nbs-system/naxsi/wiki/whitelists

What is the easy way to check if this condition match in `egrep`/`sed`/`awk`/`perl`/`python` for example

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a backslash <kbd>\</kbd> in front of the pipe <kbd>|</kbd> that you want to find.

For example, `egrep '\|\|'` will match your example of an invalid rule but not your example of a valid rule.

Watch out for basic and extended regular expressions (BRE and ERE), you need a backslash for ERE but not for BRE. grep uses BRE, egrep and awk and python and perl use ERE as far as the pipe character is concerned, sed uses BRE unless you have and use the `-r` option for ERE.